# Why iPad can't hide Status Bar from splash?

Tags: ipad, statusbar, default.png

Greetings everyone!

I'm curious about what could solve this. I'm working on an universal app, on my iPod Touch and iPhone the status bar hides from the start of the splash image animation. However, on the iPad it only hides until the splash image is gone.

This is what i have in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```

In my info.plist...  "Status bar is initially hidden" is checked. And my code isn't setting the status bar visible again on any moment.

Any idea on what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to hide the status bar for universal apps is to go into you Info.plist; right click to add a row and select Status Bar Initially hidden.

This will ensure every time you app launches the status bar will be hidden.

[image: check screenshot]

Comment: "In my info.plist... "Status bar is initially hidden" is checked."

Comment: Its works for me,i added nothing in my delegate section,just cut "Status bar is initially hidden" is checked and add it again (not paste it),hope its work for you too..if it works just accept my vote me up :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue on the iPad as well. Believe it or not my problem was to delete the Info.plist and add it again with exactly the same data as previously entered.